# No virtual method getTable()Lio/realm/internal/TableOrView

Tags: java, android, realm

I´m using Realm 2.0.2 and I get this error. 
I´ve a customize RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter. 
Any idea ?

```
11-09 15:45:11.122 9877-9877/com.codi6.proyect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.codi6.proyect, PID: 9877
                                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTable()Lio/realm/internal/TableOrView; in class Lio/realm/RealmResults; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.RealmResults' appears in /data/data/com.codi6.proyect/files/instant-run/dex/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-2.1.1_ff7f4a8f1f4f385bcd3dc4aabb40b1b4ad26ff2c-classes.dex)
                                                                 at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.<init>(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:167)
                                                                 at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.<init>(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:133)
                                                                 at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.<init>(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:123)
                                                                 at com.codi6.proyect.adapters.TaskRealmAdapter.<init>(TaskRealmAdapter.java:0)
                                                                 at com.codi6.proyect.activity.MainActivity1.onCreate(MainActivity1.java:88)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ThorbenPrimke` library `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview) (`'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.23'`) is updated only to Realm 1.1.0.

It is not updated to Realm 2.x.

That library also relies on package-internal logic that no longer exists.

Solution: do not use the library, or revert Realm version to 1.1.1.

---

You can however use [Realm-Android-Adapters](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) and `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, 1.3.0

Comment: Any tip on how to change from RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter to RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: You kinda need to DIY the swipe refresh and the loading at the bottom, and headers can be done with decorations (like `header-decor` library) -- but you don't need to do anything special for animations anymore, and that is where the real magic was in RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter. Now Realm handles that